# wrapping text longtable with multiple row

Tags: longtable, multirow

I have the following table that I want to reproduce:

[image]

So far, my best attempt is the following:

[image]

The table goes beyond page margins, and I have been trying to adjust the width and height of the cells manually to make it fit.

Is there a way that the cells will auto-adjust on the multirows, like in the rest of the cells?

My MWE is the following:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
  \usepackage{xltabular}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{tabu}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{longtable}{@{}| l | c | *{5}{c|} @{}}
 \hline
 \textbf{Set} & \textbf{Condition} & \textbf{Load [N]} & \textbf{Max. Speed 
 [mm/s]} & \textbf{Trapezoidal Motion Profil}\\ \hline
 \endfirsthead
 \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{\tablename\ \thetable, continued from previous page}} 
 \\ \hline
 \textbf{Set} & \textbf{Condition} & \textbf{Load [N]} & \textbf{Max. Speed 
 [mm/s]} & \textbf{Trapezoidal Motion Profil}\\ \hline
 \endhead
 \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{Continued on next page} \\ 
 \endfoot
 \endlastfoot
 \hline
1 & \multirow{5}{*}{Fault-free} & -44 & 40 & \multirow{2}{*}{40 mm, 1 s (10 
+ 10 seconds hold)} \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
2 &   & 0 & 40 &    \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
3 & & 0 & 80 & \multirow{2}{*}{40 mm, 21 s (0.5 + 0.5 seconds motion, 10 + 10 seconds hold)} \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
4 &  & 44 & 80 &  \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
5 & & 0 & 40 & 80 mm, 24 s (2+2 seconds motion, 10 + 10 seconds hold)  \\ \hline
6 & \multirow{5}{2cm}{Partial jam in screw return channel} &  -44 & 40 & 
\multirow{2}{3cm}{40 mm, 22 s (1+1 seconds motion, 10 + 10 seconds hold)} \\ 
[60pt] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
7 &  & 0 & 40 &  \\  \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
8 &  & 0 & 80 & \multirow{2}{4cm}{40 mm, 21 s (0.5 + 0.5 seconds motion, 10+10 
seconds hold)}  \\[60pt] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
9 &  & 44 & 80 &  \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
10 &  & 0 & 40 & 80 mm, 24 s (2 + 2 seconds motion, 10 + 10 seconds hold) \\ 
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small variation of nice [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) answer. slightly differences are:

- use of the `siunitx` package for values with units
- different type of the second column
- different formatting of cells contents in the last column
- use of `\caption` for table captions

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
   \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
  \usepackage{makecell, multirow, ltablex}
  \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

   \begin{document}

  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                              |c|
                >{\raggedright}m{25mm}
                              |S[table-format=-2.0]|
                               S[table-format= 2.0]|
                               X|
                              @{}}
  \caption{my table}
  \label{tab:longtable}                                   \\
      \Xhline{1pt}
  \thead{Set}
      &   \thead{Condition}
          &   {\thead{Load\\ {[N]}}}
              &   {\thead{Max.\\ Speed\\ {[mm/s]}}}
                  &   \thead{Trapezoidal Motion Profil}   \\
      \Xhline{0.5pt}
  \endfirsthead
  \caption{my table (cont.)}                     \\
      \Xhline{0.6pt}
  \thead{Set}
      &   \thead{Condition}
          &   {\thead{Load\\ {[N]}}}
              &   {\thead{Max.\\ Speed\\ {[mm/s]}}}
                  &   \thead{Trapezoidal Motion Profil}   \\
      \Xhline{0.3pt}
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\textit{Continued on next page}}  \\
  \endfoot
      \Xhline{0.6pt}
  \endlastfoot
  1 & \multirow{6}{=}{Fault-free}
          & -44   & 40 & \multirow{2.2}{=}{\SI{40}{mm}, \SI{21}{s}\newline
                         (\SI{0.5}{s} + \SI{0.5}{s} motion,
                          \SI{10}{s} + \SI{10}{s} hold)}  \\
      \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
  2 &     &   0   & 40 &                                  \\
      \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}
  3 &     &   0   & 80 & \multirow{2.2}{=}{\SI{40}{mm}, \SI{21}{s}\newline
                         (\SI{0.5}{s} + \SI{0.5}{s} motion,
                          \SI{10}{s} + \SI{10}{s} hold)}  \\
      \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
  4   &   &  44   & 80 &                                  \\
      \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}
  5   &   &   0   & 40 & \SI{80}{mm}, \SI{24}{s}\newline
                         (\SI{2}{s} + \SI{2}{s} motion,
                         \SI{10}{s} + \SI{10}{s} hold)   \\
      \hline
  6   & \multirow{6}{=}{Partial jam in screw return channel}
          & -44   & 40 & \multirow{2.2}{=}{\SI{40}{mm}, \SI{22}{s}\newline
                         (\SI{1}{s} + \SI{1}{s} motion,
                          \SI{10}{s} + \SI{10}{s} hold)}   \\
      \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
  7   &   &   0   & 40 &                                  \\
  \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
  8   &   &   0   & 80 & \multirow{2.2}{=}{\SI{40}{mm}, \SI{21}{s}\newline
                         (\SI{0.5}{s} + \SI{0.5}{s} motion,
                          \SI{10}{s} + \SI{10}{s} hold)}  \\
      \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
  9   &   &  44   & 80 &                                  \\
      \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}
  10  &   &   0   & 40 & \SI{80}{mm}, \SI{24}{s}\newline
                         (\SI{2}{s} + \SI{2}{s} motion,
                         \SI{10}{s} + \SI{10}{s} hold)   \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \endgroup
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `\ltablex`, `makecell` and `siunitx`:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
 \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}
  \usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

 \begin{document}

\noindent
\sisetup{detect-weight}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}c |S[table-format=-2.0]| S[table-format=2.0]|X!{\vrule width 1pt}@{}}
 \Xhline{1pt}
 \thead{Set} & \thead{Condition} & {\thead{Load [N]}} & {\thead{Max.\\ Speed\\ {[\si{mm/s}]}}} & \thead{Trapezoidal Motion Profil}\\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
 \endfirsthead
 \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{\tablename \thetable} {continued from previous page}}
 \\ \Xhline{1pt}
 \thead{Set} & \thead{Condition} & {\thead{Load [N]}} & {\thead{Max. \\Speed\\
 {[\si{mm/s}]}}} & \thead{Trapezoidal Motion Profil}\\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
 \endhead
 \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{Continued on next page} \\
 \Xhline{0.8pt}
 \endfoot
 \Xhline{1pt}
 \endlastfoot
1 & \multirow{6}{*}{Fault-free} & -44 & 40 & \multirow{2}{=}{40 mm, 1 s (10
+ 10 seconds hold)} \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
2 & & 0 & 40 & \\
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
3 & & 0 & 80 & \multirow{2}{=}{40 mm, 21 s (0.5 + 0.5 seconds motion, 10 + 10 seconds hold)} \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
4 & & 44 & 80 & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
5 & & 0 & 40 & 80 mm, 24 s (2+2 seconds motion, 10 + 10 seconds hold) \\ \hline
6 & \multirow{6}{2.5cm}{Partial jam in screw return channel} & -44 & 40 &
 \multirow{2}{=}{40 mm, 22 s (1+1 seconds motion, 10 + 10 seconds hold)} \\
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
7 & & 0 & 40 & \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
8 & & 0 & 80 & \multirow{2}{=}{40 mm, 21 s (0.5 + 0.5 seconds motion, 10+10
seconds hold)} \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
9 & & 44 & 80 & \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
10 & & 0 & 40 & 80 mm, 24 s (2 + 2 seconds motion, 10 + 10 seconds hold)
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]